# Matrix of a linear transformation with matrices as vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

let $\mathbb{M}_{N}(\mathbb{R})$ be the matrices of size $N$x$N$ with real coefficients, that is clearly a vector space.

Also the transformation:
\begin{align*}
f : \mathbb{M}_{N}&(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{M}_{N}(\mathbb{R}) \\
    &X \to CXC^T
\end{align*}

is clearly linear, as:

$$f(\alpha X_1 + \beta X_1)= C(\alpha X_1 + \beta X_1)C^t=\alpha C X_1 C^t + \beta C X_2 C^t= \alpha f(X_1)+\beta f(X_2)$$

Also it is known that every linear transformation between vector spaces can be represented as a matrix, but I dont get how that matrix would be in this case.

The canonical base of the vector space is $\{ e_1 , \cdots ,e_{N^2} \}$ so I guess the matrix is of size $N^2 \times N^2$, but i dont really get how the coefficients would be

Comment: Hello, could you clarify what you mean by $e_i$? The canonical basis of $M_N(\mathbb{R})$ is formed by matrices $E_{ij}$, $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,N\}$, where every entry is $0$ except entry $ij$ which is $1$.

Comment: @Jim I think you might find the first part of my [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3100937/81360) to be helpful

Comment: i meant $E_{ij}$ didnt remember that notation

Comment: @BenGrossmann it does kinda help, not familiarized with that but it is more or less what I expected, thanks!

Comment: @JimSimons In brief, one matrix representation of this transformation is the Kronecker product $C\otimes C$